# Dynamically Tally Child Elements by Classname in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a page that allows a user to drag/drop images into pre-defined DIVs, then I tally up the total value of the images based on their class name.  What I am trying to do is get vue to read the values from each outer `div.answer` and get the class names of the child images.

My source code is:

```
<div
    is="box-answers"
    v-for="box in boxes.slice().reverse()"
    v-bind:key="box.id"
    v-bind:level="box.level"
    v-bind:hint="box.hint"
></div>

<script>
Vue.component('box-answers', {
    props: ['level','hint'],
    template: '<div class="droppable answer :id="level" :title="hint"></div>'
});

new Vue({ 
    el: '#mainapp',
    data: {
        boxes: [
            { id: 1, level: 'baselevel-1', hint: 'x 1' },
            { id: 2, level: 'baselevel-2', hint: 'x 20' },
            { id: 3, level: 'baselevel-3', hint: 'x 400' },
            { id: 4, level: 'baselevel-4', hint: 'x 8,000' },
            { id: 5, level: 'baselevel-5', hint: 'x 160,000' }
        ]
    }
</script>
```

This converts to the follow HTML (the nested DIVs and SPANs are user-possible entries by dragging):

```
    <div id="baselevel-5" class="droppable answer" title="x 160,000">
      <div><img src="images/line.gif" alt="Five" class="imgfive"></div>
      <span><img src="images/dot.gif" alt="One" class="imgone"></span>
    </div>
    ...
    <div id="baselevel-1" class="droppable answer" title="x 1">
      <span><img src="images/line.gif" alt="One" class="imgone"></span>
    </div>
```

Currently, I have jQuery/JavaScript calculating the point values using the following:

```
$(function(j) {
var arAnswers = Array(1);
count = 0; //
j("div.answer").each(function( idx ) {
    currentId = j(this).attr('id');
    ones = 0;
    fives = 0;

    if ( j("#" + currentId).children().length > 0 ) {
        ones = j("#" + currentId).children().find("img.imgone").length * 1;
        fives = j("#" + currentId).children().find("img.imgfive").length * 5;
        arAnswers[count] = ones + fives; //Tally box value

        count++;
    }
});
});
```

I would like Vue to perform similar iteration and addition to return total value of ones and fives found based on the image classname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you are approaching this problem as a pure-play DOM operation. If that is what you need then you can simply use `$refs`:

```
<!-- NOTICE ref -->
<div ref="boxAnswers"
    is="box-answers"
    v-for="box in boxes.slice().reverse()"
    v-bind:key="box.id"
    v-bind:level="box.level"
    v-bind:hint="box.hint">
</div>
```

Inside your high-level component, you will have a function like:

```
function calculate() {
    // NOTICE $refs
    const arAnswers = this.$refs.boxAnswers.map((x) => {

        // $el is the DOM element
        const once = x.$el.querySelectorAll('img.imgone').length * 1;
        const fives = x.$el.querySelectorAll('img.imgfive').length * 5;

        return once + fives

    });

    return arAnswers;

}
```

**But this is not the correct Vue way of doing things.** You have to think in terms of events and data model (MVVM - don't touch DOM. DOM is just a representation of your data model). Since, you have a drag-n-drop based application, you have to listen for `drag`, `dragstart`, `dragend` and other `drag` events. For example:

```
<!-- NOTICE drop event -->
<div @drop="onDropEnd(box, $event)"
    is="box-answers"
    v-for="box in boxes.slice().reverse()"
    v-bind:key="box.id"
    v-bind:level="box.level"
    v-bind:hint="box.hint">
</div>
```

Your `onDropEnd` event handler will look like:

```
function onDrop(box, $event) {

    // box - on which box drop is happening
    // $event.data - which image is being dropped

    // Verify $event.data is actually the image you are intending
    if ($event.data === 'some-type-image') {
        // Do the counting manipulations here
        // ... remaining code
    }

}
```

This is not a complete code as I don't know other components. But it should help you with the required direction.

Comment: I'm still very new to Vue so while I understand why your first answer is not the real way to do it, I'll work with that one until I get a deeper understanding of the language. Using `$refs` has opened my eyes to lots of potential!